# How to configure Jenkins to use MFA/2FA

Tags: authentication, jenkins

We would like users to use their username/password along with another form of Multifactor Authentication, such as Google Auth (or Authy), to log into Jenkins.

We did not find any plugins that support this.

We are using AWS, so one of the things we looked at was putting an ALB in front of Jenkins and then putting, but this may interfere with getting POST requests from github to trigger builds.

Any ideas on how to enable MFA on Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is recommended to use SSO (something like SAML: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SAML+Plugin) and then as part of the SSO you can implement MFA. The problem with doing MFA directly with Jenkins is that Jenkins has pretty rudimentary user management.